# How do I debug/kint Simple XML Sitemap link array?

Tags: 8, xml-sitemap

I am trying to find how I can debug/kint a variable/array from the Simple XML Sitemap?

I worked through the documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/simple-xml-sitemap/api-and-extending-the-module#s-api-hooks to find the hook I need.

My goal is to unset any links that have `node/` to remove published, but un-aliased nodes of included content types.

The array key `['path']` looks to be the unaliased URL and the below code removes all links except the home page. I am unsure how I can `kint($link)` in this function so I can see what other array keys are available to see what else I may use for comparison.

```
function HOOK_simple_sitemap_links_alter(array &$links, $sitemap_variant) {

  foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
    if (strpos($link['meta']['path'], 'node/') !== FALSE) {
      unset($links[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to `kint()` these sitemap arrays? Or maybe some documentation that shows the structure of these arrays?

Comment: Assuming you have devel installed and kint selected for output, it should be as easy as `ksm($links);` to print the kint output to the message area

Comment: I had kint enabled but not devel. `kint()` throws errors while regenerating the sitemap links, but `ksm()` does not and displays what is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Clive said, you will need to make sure that both the devel and kint modules are enabled.  (NOTE: D8's Devel 4.0 now includes the kint module but requires 'composer require kint-php/kint' to be done to make it work) Then you can add your hook and just do a `ksm($links);` statement.

Make sure to clear cache so the hook will be found.  Then doing a regenerate of the sitemap(s) in the gui will product the kint output that you can examine for the structure.

Also, not totally sure, but I think this hook has to be in a module and will not work in the .theme file.

FYI - Here's a code snippet from a working hook that does what you want, including removing untranslated nodes.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_simple_sitemap_links_alter().
 */
function my_module_simple_sitemap_links_alter(&$links, $variant) {
  foreach($links as $key => $link) {
    // Filter out any node/### URLs
    if ( preg_match("!(/[a-z-]*)?/node/\d?!", $link['url']) ) {
      unset( $links[$key] );
      continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `['url']` was the key I was looking for. I am using `if (strstr($link['url'], '/node/'))`, but this answers the need of my Q, and the above will remove `/node/` URL's. `ksm()` seemed to be the big difference in debugging.